# Why is @MasterType directive not implied when setting @Page masterPageFIle?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, master-pages, asp.net-3.5

The docs for @MasterType have this example.

```
<%@ Page  masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

Why is `@MasterType` even needed?  Couldn't the compiler automatically take the same actions based solely on `@Page masterPageFile`?  When would you not want to use both?

Comment: +1 I've wondered that so many times myself!

Answer (score 2):

You can set different master pages at each pages PreInit. So the master page is in general not well defined.

Comment: In this case I expect you wouldn't use either directive 'cause it's defined at runtime and you also wouldn't expect to get a typed `Master` property.  The question is really directed towards situations where you do use the directives and the master page is known at compile time.

Comment: But there is only one situation. Page and master page are loosely coupled. You can change the master page at runtime. The MasterPage directive is just a smart cast for simple situations and you have to take the full responsibility for it.